# Subquery in spring

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, subquery

I do not know how to write a sub-query in spring. I am looking for some hints on how to proceed?

```
SELECT * FROM CRL_CAR 
INNER JOIN CRL_ASSIGNED_CAR ON CAR_ID 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN CUSTOMER_ID = '72' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END;
```

I need to add result to predicates.

Comment: You mean in JPQL ? If yes , you need to provide the mapping first

Comment: Are you trying to use NativeQuery with  EntityManager ?

Comment: @GovindParashar yes.

Comment: Add mapping of CRL_CAR and CRL_ASSIGNED_CAR  in your question